# Background slideshow image appearing out of place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slideshow which uses background images which fade from one to the other in a countinous loop. I have a problem, that when you start the slideshow the last image appears for a moment before the first image loads.
The image that appears is off set so that its left hand edge start at the middle of the window. In Google Chrome and Safari the first image then displays where this image was while the rest with then load correctly.

I've tried several slideshows and this is most sucessful if I can remove this bug. Can anyone help me?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //Background Image Slideshow- (c) Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com) 
    //For full source code, 100's more DHTML scripts, and TOS, 
    //visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    p {
font-family:Trajan Pro, serif;
font-size:medium;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
}
    h1 {
font-family:Trajan Pro, serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:x-large;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}


    #bg {
      position:absolute;
      z-Index:0;
      top:135px;
    }

    #bg IMG{
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      opacity: -0.001;
    }

    --></style>
    <div style="height: 395px !important; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div id="bg">
            <img alt="" src="/images/image1.jpg" /> <img alt="" src="/images/image2.jpg" /> <a href="link.html"><img alt="" src="/images/image3.jpg" /></a><img alt="" src="/images/image4.jpg" /><img alt="" src="/images/image5.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Animate (11-January-2010)
    // by Vic Phillips http://www.vicsjavascripts.org.uk

    // To progressively change the Left, Top, Width, Height or Opacity of an element over a specified period of time.
    // With the ability to scale the effect time on specified minimum/maximum values
    // and with three types of progression 'sin' and 'cos' and liner.

    // **** Application Notes

    // **** The HTML Code
    //
    // when moving an element the inline or class rule style position of the element should be assigned as
    // 'position:relative;' or 'position:absolute;'
    //
    // The element would normally be assigned a unique ID name.
    //

    // **** Initialising the Script.
    //
    // The script is initialised by assigning an instance of the script to a variable.
    // e.g A = new zxcAnimate('left','id1')
    // where:
    //  A = a global variable                                                               (variable)
    //  parameter 0 = the mode(see Note 1).                                                           (string)
    //  parameter 1 = the unique ID name or element object.                                           (string or element object)
    //  parameter 1 = the initial value.                                                              (digits, default = 0)

    // **** Executing the Effect
    //
    // The effect is executed by an event call to function 'A.animate(10,800 ,5000,[10,800]);'
    // where:
    //  A           = the global referencing the script instance.                                 (variable)
    //  parameter 0 = the start value.                                                            (digits, for opacity minimum 0, maximum 100)
    //  parameter 1 = the finish value.                                                           (digits, for opacity minimum 0, maximum 100)
    //  parameter 2 =  period of time between the start and finish of the effect in milliseconds. (digits or defaults to previous or 0(on first call) milliSeconds)
    //  parameter 3 = (optional) to scale the effect time on a specified minimum/maximum.         (array, see Note 3)
    //                 field 0 the minimum value. (digits)
    //                 field 1 the maximum value. (digits)
    //  parameter 3 = (optional) the type of progression, 'sin', 'cos' or 'liner'.                (string, default = 'liner')
    //                 'sin' progression starts fast and ends slow.
    //                 'cos' progression starts slow and ends fast.
    //
    //  Note 1:  Examples modes: 'left', 'top', 'width', 'height', 'opacity.
    //  Note 2:  The default units(excepting opacity) are 'px'.
    //           For hyphenated modes, the first character after the hyphen must be upper case, all others lower case.
    //  Note 3:  The scale is of particular use when re-calling the effect
    //           in mid progression to retain an constant rate of progression.
    //  Note 4:  The current effect value is recorded in A.data[0].
    //  Note 5:  A function may be called on completion of the effect by assigning the function
    //           to the animator intance property .Complete.
    //           e.g. [instance].Complete=function(){ alert(this.data[0]); };
    //



    // **** Functional Code(1.58K) - NO NEED to Change

    function zxcAnimate(mde,obj,srt){
     this.to=null;
     this.obj=typeof(obj)=='object'?obj:document.getElementById(obj);
     this.mde=mde.replace(/\W/g,'');
     this.data=[srt||0];
     return this;
    }

    zxcAnimate.prototype.animate=function(srt,fin,ms,scale,c){
     clearTimeout(this.to);
     this.time=ms||this.time||0;
     this.neg=srt<0||fin<0;
     this.data=[srt,srt,fin];
     this.mS=this.time*(!scale?1:Math.abs((fin-srt)/(scale[1]-scale[0])));
     this.c=typeof(c)=='string'?c.charAt(0).toLowerCase():this.c?this.c:'';
     this.inc=Math.PI/(2*this.mS);
     this.srttime=new Date().getTime();
     this.cng();
    }

    zxcAnimate.prototype.cng=function(){
     var oop=this,ms=new Date().getTime()-this.srttime;
     this.data[0]=(this.c=='s')?                (this.data[2]-this.data[1])*Math.sin(this.inc*ms)+this.data[1]:(this.c=='c')?this.data[2]-(this.data[2]-this.data[1])*Math.cos(this.inc*ms):(this.data[2]-this.data[1])/this.mS*ms+this.data[1];
     this.apply();
     if (ms<this.mS) this.to=setTimeout(function(){oop.cng()},10);
     else {
      this.data[0]=this.data[2];
      this.apply();
      if (this.Complete) this.Complete(this);
     }
    }

    zxcAnimate.prototype.apply=function(){
     if (isFinite(this.data[0])){
      if (this.data[0]<0&&!this.neg) this.data[0]=0;
      if (this.mde!='opacity') this.obj.style[this.mde]=Math.floor(this.data[0])+'px';
      else zxcOpacity(this.obj,this.data[0]);
     }
    }

    function zxcOpacity(obj,opc){
     if (opc<0||opc>100) return;
     obj.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opc+')';
     obj.style.opacity=obj.style.MozOpacity=obj.style.KhtmlOpacity=opc/100-.001;
    }


    </script><script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    function BGFade(o){
     var p=document.getElementById(o.ID)
     if (p){
      var bgs=p.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
      this.bgs=[];
      for (var z0=0;z0<bgs.length;z0++){
       this.bgs[z0]=new zxcAnimate('opacity',bgs[z0]);
      }
      this.nu=z0-1;
      this.ms=o.Duration||1000;
      this.hold=o.Hold||this.ms*2;
      if(this.nu>0){
       this.Rotate();
      }
     }
    }

    BGFade.prototype.Rotate=function(){
     this.bgs[this.nu].obj.style.zIndex='0';
     this.bgs[this.nu].animate(100,0,this.ms);
     this.nu=++this.nu%this.bgs.length;
     this.bgs[this.nu].obj.style.zIndex='1';
     this.bgs[this.nu].obj.style.left=-(this.bgs[this.nu].obj.width-zxcWWHS()[0])/2+'px';  // horizontal center
    // this.bgs[this.nu].obj.style.top=-(this.bgs[this.nu].obj.height-zxcWWHS()[1])/2+'px';  // vertical center
     this.bgs[this.nu].animate(0,100,this.ms);
     var oop=this;
     this.to=setTimeout(function(){ oop.Rotate(); },this.hold);
    }

    function zxcByClassName(nme,el,tag){
     if (typeof(el)=='string') el=document.getElementById(el);
     el=el||document;
     for (var tag=tag||'*',reg=new RegExp('\\b'+nme+'\\b'),els=el.getElementsByTagName(tag),ary=[],z0=0; z0<els.length;z0++){
      if(reg.test(els[z0].className)) ary.push(els[z0]);
     }
     return ary;
    }

    function zxcWWHS(){
     if (window.innerHeight) return [window.innerWidth-10,window.innerHeight-10,window.pageXOffset,window.pageYOffset];
     else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight) return [document.documentElement.clientWidth-10,document.documentElement.clientHeight-10,document.documentElement.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollTop];
     return [document.body.clientWidth,document.body.clientHeight,document.body.scrollLeft,document.body.scrollTop];
    }


    new BGFade({
     ID:'bg',        // the unique id name of the container div.                    (string)
     Duration:3000,  // the duration of the fade effect in milli seconds.           (digits)
     Hold:5000       // the duration of the change between images in milli seconds. (digits)
    });
    //-->
    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated since I'm really at a loss of what to do here.

Comment: If possible please fiddle your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: How do I use JSFiddle? I assume I need to sign in. When I save what I've done, will it give me a link to place here to allow you to see it?

Comment: When it places the first image, it sets the left position of being over 500 and then the second time round corrects it. What I need it to do is either calculate the position first, or be able to set the initial position. Is that possible?

Comment: I think the last image appears, to allow the first image to have something to fade in from. How would I set the initial image or just have it to fade in from something blank? That might solve half the problem.

Comment: You can use JSFiddle without Signup.  Once you complete editing the code, save it and copy the URL then paste it here.

Comment: Okay. I've give that a go.

Comment: I hope you already got the answer.  Here is your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Cpz6Q/).  Please update it with the missing one.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant about the missing one but I thought I may as well sign up to JSFiddle since it looks like I may find it useful. The one you posted has the same problem as well as the one I've uploaded.
One brief note: I said that the first image was shifted to the right, but that becuase I was using large images. The test images I've used are smaller so now the image is shifted to the left.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeredDrahcur/b3Vr4/1/)

Comment: Have you checked my JSFiddle2 in my answer?

Comment: +1 for your instant comments and I enjoyed being a part of it, eventhough my contribution was less :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Cpz6Q/1/) it is clear that everything is working fine except the last image is shown at the initial stage.  I'm not sure this is correct fix, yet I hope this solves your problem.

```
this.bgs[this.nu].animate(1, 0, this.ms);
```

I reduced the animation time from 100 to 1.

Checkout this [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Cpz6Q/1/)

**Quick Fix:** Forget about everything we did.  As you mentioned in your comment, let have a **invisible image** at the last like below:

```
<div id="bg">
    <a href=""><img alt="Pyramifern" src="http://www.maoptp.co.uk/pyramifern.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img alt="Pyramifern at sunrise" src="http://www.maoptp.co.uk/pyramifern_at_sunrise.jpg" /></a> 
    <a href=""><img alt="Pyramifern at sunset" src="http://www.maoptp.co.uk/pyramifern_at_sunset.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img alt="Pyramifern at night" src="http://www.maoptp.co.uk/pyramifern_at_night.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""><img alt="Nocturnal flowers" src="http://www.maoptp.co.uk/nocturnal_flowers.jpg" /></a>
    <a href=""> <img alt="Nocturnal flowers" style="display: none;" src="http://www.maoptp.co.uk/nocturnal_flowers.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Jpf4V/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: It stops the last image appearing first but that remove the fade out which was the reason I uses that script in the first place.

Comment: Also, if I load the page the image is in place but if I refresh it, it appears out of place on Google Chrome. I can live with the last image appearing first but I need get fix the image appearing out of place.

Comment: Although it is rather messy, I might be able to fix it with a blank image as the first image and the container background set. The only problem is without your solution the last picture appears briefly and with your solution the background image appears after each other image disappears. 
I tired fixing that but having the first image last which is not bad although it fades to its self at the end. If you can suggest a way to stop the last image showing without removing the fade out, that should fix it - at least for now.

Comment: @RichardYoung I was also thinking of that.  Let me try for a quick fix.

Comment: @RichardYoung Hope JSFiddle3 in my answer will give a quick fix.

Comment: That looks **brilliant!** Let me try it on the actual site I'm working on and I'll get back to you.

Comment: That's not really working either. It still shows a blank image at the end with and doesn't fix the position of the first image, or are you suggesting I combine it with my idea of having a background image as well as the invisible one?
If I use the background idea and take out the first image, is there a way set the a five second delay before it starts?

Comment: @RichardYoung From JSFiddle3, the only thing I noticed that there is a little time delay in animation rather than everything is working.  But position look correct?  Please check with JSFiddle3.

Comment: @RichardYoung The image seems to be in different size that may concern you.  Lets have specific width and height for images like here in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Jpf4V/2/)

Comment: The position looks correct in JSFiddle but if you view it full screen then you do see it. Sometimes the position is okay in Firefox but in Google Chrome it ins't.

Comment: I think I can fix it if I use the setTimeout function. You you know which function I need to do it on?

Comment: I've put the blank image first and last and used the background on the main division so. It just makes the first image appear fot twice as long as the others.

Comment: @RichardYoung At Last you found a fix for your problem :) If possible please share it in JSFiddle.

Comment: @RichardYoung thats fine :)